# Launching add contacts activity with website information

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to launch the native add contact activity with some data. I figured out most of it. Now I am just stuck trying to send the website through the intent. Here's the code

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

    // Just some examples of information you can send to pre-fill out data for the
    // user. See android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert for the complete
    // list.
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Foo");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "123456");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "foo@foo.com");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "foo drive, foo");

    startActivity(intent);
```

android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert does not have a website field. Is there any other way to pass data?

Answer (score 5):

Use this to add the website url :

```
  ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

  ContentValues row1 = new ContentValues();
  row1.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  row1.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL, "www.urwebsite.com");
  row1.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.LABEL, "abc");
  row1.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE, Website.TYPE_HOME);
  data.add(row1);
  intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution, but it gives an error -> DATA cannot be resolved or is not a field  - which is strange because it is mentioned in the documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html

Comment: Did you import ContactsContract.Intents.Insert? There is one more Insert class "Contacts.Intents.Insert". Dont import this

Comment: I directly tried this -> intent1.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);

Comment: THis is supported only from HoneyComb (Ver 11 ). If you are targeting for 11 or greater you can use it.

Comment: I am targeting 2.3+ so cannot use it :(